# Android on Raspberry Pi

Tags: android

Is there a way to run Android on a Raspberry Pi? Or at least run Android apps?
I know there are ways to run Android apps in Chrome, but does this work on the Pi?

Comment: Check out the community Razdroid project, hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the community driven [Razdroid project](http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki) that is however - as of today - far from being able to provide a finished version of Android for the RPi. It is stated that they mainly suffer from a proper port of hardware acceleration drivers for the Broadcom SoC used on the RPi. So - again as of today - depending on your usage the RPi might not be the best platform to run Android at a high performance.

**Update May 2016**

[Arstechnica](http://arstechnica.co.uk/gadgets/2016/05/raspberry-pi-3-android-support-details/) found some evidence of *future* Android support for the Pi3:

> In Google's Android Open Source Project (AOSP) repository, a new device tree recently popped up for the Raspberry Pi 3. [...] For now, the Ri 3 [sic] device tree is empty with only the comment "initial empty repository" accompanying it. The repository should soon start to fill with code, though.

Answer (score 2):

[Android Pi Wikia](http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki) is a forum for an unofficial version of Android for Pi