# Using Raspberry Pi as Android Tablet

Tags: android

Is it possible to run Android or CyanogenMod on a Raspberry Pi directly?

Comment: Also related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23805/android-on-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been attempts to port Android to the RPi, but there hasn't been any progress made on any of them in quite some time, and performance has always been horrible.

I wouldn't recommend it.